# In Pyside2, when I subclass QSqlTableModel how do I write the data method without generating maximum recursion depth errors?

Tags: python, pyside, subclassing

I have a working application in Pyside2 that displays a QSqlTableModel in a QSqlTableView.
Three of the fields display raw seconds, like "6282" meaning six thousand and some seconds into a video.  I want to change the appearance of those fields in the displayed table, and in the Word document I extract from them to be in the form "h:mm:ss".

I concluded I had to subclass QSqlTableModel, in particular, the data function in it, to do this.  But I'm stuck.  See code, with comments noting the place where I'm stuck.

```
class myQSqlTableModel(PySide2.QtSql.QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self, db: QSqlDatabase):
        super().__init__()
        self.DB = db

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        # ********** Stuck right here ***************
        # Below attempts generate maximum recursion depth errors as they eventually call this function over and over
        # self.selectRow(index.row())
        # val = self.record(index.row()).value(index.column())
        # val = index.sibling(index.row(), index.column())
        # item = self.itemData(index)
        # for key in item:
        #     print(f"key is {key}, value is {item[key].ToString()}")

        # The examples for QAbstractTableModel do this by calling an internal function like "_items"
        # which references a two-dimensional list (a list of lists, where the inner list is a list of field values.
        # See https://www.pythonguis.com/faq/remove-and-insertrow-for-martin-fitzpatricks-example/
        # But how do I do that sort of thing with a QSqlTableModel??
        # Or should I be subclassing QSqlTableModel at all, instead of something else?
        # *********** End of Stuck Comment ***********

        if role==Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            # Changing this to format raw seconds as h:mm:ss for some fields
            col_name = self.headerData(index.column(), Qt.Horizontal, Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
            if col_name in ['start', 'end', 'duration']:
                x = val
                s = x % 60
                m = (x // 60) % 60
                h = x // 3600
                print("%01d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s))
                return "%01d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s)
            else:
                return val
        return None

class Ui_ExportWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_ExportWindow):
    def __init__(self, DB):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # self.dbFile = settings['dbFile']
        #
        # # Get a valid database setup
        # self.DB = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")  # loads the driver for Sqlite
        # self.DB.setDatabaseName(self.dbFile)  # the actual physical file
        # self.DB.open()  # open the DB

        self.DB = DB
        self.dbFile = settings['dbFile']
        self.doc_folder = settings['export_folder']

# Skip a bunch of irrelevant stuff

       # Configure the QtableView for Utterances
        self.umodel = myQSqlTableModel(self.DB)  # Edit triggers are turned off in designer
```

The application has been working well in production for a year, I'm just trying to add this feature request, which has me very puzzled.  I'd really appreciate any advice on where I might be going wrong in this approach.

I researched the web for two days looking at all sorts of posts about customizing displays -- most of which seemed to be about highlighting, and fonts and that sort of thing, rather than transforming the input of an integer into output of a formatted string.

I tried three different ways of accessing the values of the record in the QSqlTableModel, all of which generated recursion errors, and all of which are shown in the sample code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `itemData()` internally calls `data()`, that's your recursion. To get the default behavior, you always use `super().<function>(<arguments>)`, eg: `val = super().data(index, role)`. Note that an override should always return the expected result whenever you're not doing something else: the final `return None` is not only pointless (`None` is implicit in `return`, and `return` is implicit at the end of every function), but you are also *not* returning the existing values of other roles, most importantly the `EditRole`, which is required for delegate editing. Change the last line to `return val`.

Comment: Thanks to musicamante for the correct answer.  I cleaned up my code and it worked perfectly.  It turns out I missed the other answer this is now linked to, and that gave the correct answer also.

The question is closed already so I don't see how to mark musicamante's response as correct.   
  I really appreciate this very rapid response and the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't worry, comments are not answers and as such cannot be "accepted"; also, there is no need to create/accept another answer,  since a duplicated question already exists with its own answer. You have 15 rep, so you can upvote that instead, if you want. Note that that answer uses the old "static" way of accessing methods of the parent class (`parentClass.method(instance, <args>)`), which is still valid in certain cases where absolute control over which class should be queried is required. In normal conditions, `super().method(<args>)` is preferred.